# logging debug messages to console in c#

Tags: c#

I have a very very basic c# question about logging debug-trace messages on console. For redirecting the trace message to console, we can use

```
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
```

I was expecting something similar to exist for logging debug message to console.

```
    //Debug.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleDebugListener()); //does not exist
    Debug.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
```

so the name does not make a difference or am i missing something.

**EDIT**

I just wanted to know if something like **ConsoleDebugListener** or something similar exist or not. it works with trace listener though.

Comment: It works for me. Are you definitely running a DEBUG build of the console app?

Comment: i know it works... why question is, why something similar does not exist for debug listner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConsoleTraceListener` is a class that handles how to write messages coming its way; even though it contains `Trace` it is not the exclusive output method for the `Trace` class in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

If you want to really find why the `ConsoleTraceListener` works for both `Debug` and `Trace`, it is because both of them use the `TraceInternal` class internally, which then sends messages to the listeners it contains. Maybe that's a good enough reason for the initial listeners to have been called `*Trace*` (`EventLogTraceListener`, `XmlWriterTraceListener`, etc...)

Interestingly, listeners are shared between `Debug` and `Trace` since they both return the `TraceInternal` property.

Comment: great. thanks a lot. I was just little curious, nothing else. something works, but if it has a little quirk, wanted to find out why. thanks a lot for detailed answer.